# How to get the last selected item or its index in html multiple select using VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, internet-explorer

As given on msdn about HtmlSelect.SelectedIndex Property

> If the Multiple property is set to true, indicating that multiple items can be concurrently selected, the SelectedIndex property contains the index of the first selected item.

I am using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer APIs in my Vb.Net WinForms application and I am trying to get the text of last selected item by the user but SelectedIndex is not working for me in case of multiple HTML Select.

Here's my code

```
 Private Sub onMouseDown(ByVal pEvtObj As mshtml.IHTMLEventObj)
    Dim srcElement = pEvtObj.srcElement
    If TypeOf (srcElement) Is IHTMLSelectElement Then
        Dim DropDownElement = CType(srcElement, IHTMLSelectElement)
        Dim elementValue = CType(DropDownElement.item(DropDownElement.selectedIndex), IHTMLOptionElement).text
    End If
End Sub
```

Can anybody let me know how to do it?

Comment: Just a guess out of experience with such objects: is there an SelectedIndices Property?

Comment: No there is no such property.

Comment: Perhaps it's a possibility to parse the "Value" Property?

Comment: Yes, I can parse the value but it gives the value of first selected item during multiple selection.

Comment: Do you want a list of all selected items? Or do you want to know which one the user picked last?

Comment: Yes, I want to know the one user last picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not getting any straight forward way, To achieve the requirement I have used the following way:

1) Store the selected values on MouseDown and KeyDown events.

2) Also add handler to the DropDownElement for its onchange event within above two mentioned events.

3) Now when the value changes it will trigger the method on which the handler is added. Here we can get the current Selected Elements and calculate the de-selected and the last selected element.

I know its not a cleaner way but working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Grumbler85 is correct; you want the SelectedIndices property.  It's a collection that contains the zero-based indexes of all currently-selected items in the HTMLSelect control.

[HtmlSelect.SelectedIndices Property (MSDN Link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.selectedindices(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: This is won't get the OP what he wants.  If I select item 10 then item 5, then item 1, the values return from SelectedIndices would be 0,4,9.  Which one did the user select last? Unless I am reading the question incorrectly.

Comment: If that's what he wants then he can't get it in vb.NET and he'll have to use client-side script to react to the click events.  This really becomes problematic.  What if the user selects, then de-selects an item?  Dropdown list may not be the best choice for the use case.

Comment: I am working on recording user actions for automated testing, So whether user selects or de-selects I need that action which user performed. Assume that user selects item 'a' so I want item 'a' is selected then using multiple selection user selects item 'b' so I want item 'b' is selected then user de-selected item 'a' so I want item 'a' is de-selected and so on.

Comment: In order to record this type of information, you'd need to write client-side JavaScript that made AJAX calls to vb.net code in the ASPX codebehind.  That's a lot of overhead to add to your application; I would recommend looking into automated testing tools that will do this for you.